# Can I use a system account to call Invoke-RestMethod?

Tags: powershell

I want to setup a schedule task to execute call to a web api method, all on the same server.  I dont want to put the credentials of an account in clear text within the powershell script.  Is there a way to specify in the Invoke-RestMethod the credentials using a system account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Windows task scheduler you can specify which account to use to run the task when creating it, which will store the credential info in an encrypted manner on the server, then use the `UseDefaultCredentials` switch available on `Invoke-RestMethod`